# Visual studio codeのファイル検索の補完機能を通常の検索でも使いたい

Tags: vscode

Visual Studio Codeのファイル検索(Ctrl + P)では、かなりあいまいな入力でも補完してくれますが、この補完を通常の検索(Ctrl+F、Ctrl+Shift+Fなど)でも使える方法がありますでしょうか？もしくはプラグインなどがあれば教えてください。
いつも正規表現をこねくり回してやっていますが、面倒でして。。

Comment: fuzzy-searchというやつでしばらく運用してみることにします。
全部大文字のシンボルとかに対してうまくヒットしなかったりと残念なところはありますが、なだめてすかして使ってみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

機能拡張の[Go to Fuzzy in current file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbaumier.go-to-fuzzy)が所望の機能を有しているように思われます。
(ただし、 Requirements にあるように、対応OSは Linux と MacOS に限られているようです。)

他にも、 ["fuzzy" で検索](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=fuzzy&target=VSCode)するといくつかそれっぽい説明が為されているものが見つかります。
また、 fzf, grep, ripgrep といったタグが付いているものも見てみると良いかも知れません。